# Use existing MySQL database in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, localization, multilingual

In my PHP websites I’m using [SiteTranslator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sitetranslator/) script for a website translated into 30 languages. Each translation is stored in its own table (text_en, text_de...) and each table has 3 columns (textKey, textValue, lastUpdate).

Now I would like to use that database in my CodeIgniter application.
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? To use it, you have to read the CodeIgniter user guide, especially the Database Class part: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: your question is too broad ,try something specific

Comment: If you want to use it alongside another database, you can connect to multiple databases. Read more in the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple databases as suggested, you would still need to setup your app language files

*{read more in the user guide}*

Based on the first uri segment you could try something like this.

**Adding routes**

```
$route['en|fr|gr/test'] = 'test';
```

First segment checks for **en** OR **fr** OR whatever else.

Then the **Main Controller** catches the first segment before the **test** controller is initialized and the **db(object)** && **app(language)** files are set

**www.site.com/en/test** => load english language file(*application/language/english/mylanguage*) and db

**www.site.com/fr/test** => load french language file(*application/language/french/mylanguage*) and db ...and so on

**Main Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    protected $lang, $db;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->set_language();
    }

    protected function set_language(){
        switch($this->uri->segment(1))
        {
            case 'en':
                $this->lang     = $this->lang->load('mylanguage', 'english');
                $this->db       = $this->load->database('en', TRUE); 
            break;

            case 'fr':
                $this->lang     = $this->lang->load('mylanguage', 'french');
                $this->db       = $this->load->database('fr', TRUE); 
            break;

            default:
                $this->lang     = $this->lang->load('mylanguage', 'english');
                $this->db       = $this->load->database('en', TRUE); 
            break;
        }
    }


}
```